# TCL Sort program without using lsort

Tags: sorting, tcl

using any sorting technique

array Variable arr contained :
arr { 1 5 2 9 3 8 10 6}

Without using lsort

finally o/p to be in same array variable : 
arr { 1 2 3 5 6 8 9 10}

Comment: Please provide TCL program

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me!

Comment: Btw, I've used google and found [this wiki](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Tcl).

Comment: Lots of algorithms [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms) -- take your pick.

Comment: We generally won't write your code for you @Punith. We do however help people with practical problems they face. That is, if they have written some code to solve a problem, but it doesn't work, then we have no problem helping them if they clearly demonstrate what they have done so far and where exactly they are stuck. So please do your best to solve your problem, and if you somehow get stuck somewhere, let us know by asking a clear question with all the necessary information. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we won't give you the answer, we can suggest a few useful things. For example, you compare two elements of a list (at `$idx1` and `$idx2`) with this:

```
string compare [lindex $theList $idx1] [lindex $theList $idx2]
```

And you might use this procedure to swap those two elements:

```
proc swap {nameOfListVar idx1 idx2} {
    upvar 1 $nameOfListVar theList
    set tmp [lindex $theList $idx1]
    lset theList $idx1 [lindex $theList $idx2]
    lset theList $idx2 $tmp
    return
}
```

Which you'd call like:

```
# Pass the list variable *name*
swap theList $idx1 $idx2
```

Generally, you can do a sorting algorithm like this:

- While the list is not sorted,

  - find a pair of elements in the wrong order and swap them.

Everything else is optimization. (Bear in mind that real Tcl programs just use `lsort` because it implements an efficient algorithm with many good properties, and the rest either don't need sorting or delegate the problem to a database engine…)