# Sort a list without using built-in function

Tags: list, sorting, tcl

I'm new in Tcl and trying to do this:

```
sortList :: { 3 6 8 7 0 1 4 2 9 5 } -> { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 }
```

This is my code:

```
set lst [list 3 6 8 7 0 1 4 2 9 5]
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength "$lst"]} {incr i} {
    for {set j 0} {$j < [llength "$lst"]-1 } {incr j} {
        if {[lindex $lst $j] > [lindex $lst $j+1]} { 
            set min [lindex $lst $j+1]
            set [lindex $lst $j+1] [lindex $lst $j]
            set [lindex $lst $j] $min
        }
    }
}
puts $lst
```

But it keeps print the same list:

`3 6 8 7 0 1 4 2 9 5`

i need help as fast as possible please thank you.

Comment: Homework? Assigning to the result of `lindex` won't change the list. Look up `lset`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091890/tcl-sort-program-without-using-lsort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091890/tcl-sort-program-without-using-lsort)

Comment: thank you problem solved using lset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is with these two lines:

```
        set [lindex $lst $j+1] [lindex $lst $j]
        set [lindex $lst $j] $min
```

These will be updating variables whose names happen to be small integers (because that's what is in your list); not what you want!

To ***modify*** an element of a list, you should use the `lset` command:

```
        lset list $j+1 [lindex $lst $j]
        lset lst $j $min
```

This is because lists are values; the `lset` command alters a variable to contain a new list that is the same as the old one with the modification applied to it. It does this efficiently too.

It also makes the code shorter.